# Need a new solution for disabling the home, menu buttons in android

Tags: java, android, button, android-homebutton

I have searched a lot and tried nearly everything and nothing worked for me .
I just want to disable the home and the menu buttons.

here is the LockScreenActivity.java

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mehuljoisar.lockscreen.utils.LockscreenService;
import com.mehuljoisar.lockscreen.utils.LockscreenUtils;

public class LockScreenActivity extends Activity implements
        LockscreenUtils.OnLockStatusChangedListener {

    // User-interface
    private Button btnUnlock;
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;
    private Button button3;
    private Button button4;
    private Button button5;
    private Button button6;
    private Button button7;
    private Button button8;
    private Button button9;
    private ImageButton button10;
    private TextView textView;
    private RelativeLayout myView;
    // Member variables
    private LockscreenUtils mLockscreenUtils;

    // Set appropriate flags to make the screen appear over the keyguard
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {

        this.getWindow().setType(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
        this.getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                        );

        super.onAttachedToWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lockscreen);
        init();


        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
        button7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
        button8=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
        button9=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
        button10=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button10);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        myView=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
        // Ask the System Bar to hide

        myView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+"1");
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+"8");
            }
        });

        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+"5");
            }
        });

        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+"2");
            }
        });
        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+"7");
            }
        });
        button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+"4");
            }
        });
        button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+"9");
            }
        });
        button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+"3");
            }
        });
        button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+"6");
            }
        });

        button10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(textView.getText().toString().length()>0)
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                textView.setText(textView.getText().toString().substring(0, textView.getText().toString().length()-1));
            }
        });


        // unlock screen in case of app get killed by system
        if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().hasExtra("kill")
                && getIntent().getExtras().getInt("kill") == 1) {
            enableKeyguard();
            unlockHomeButton();
        } else {

            try {
                // disable keyguard
                disableKeyguard();

                // lock home button
                lockHomeButton();

                // start service for observing intents
                startService(new Intent(this, LockscreenService.class));

                // listen the events get fired during the call
                StateListener phoneStateListener = new StateListener();
                TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
                        PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    }

    private void init() {
        mLockscreenUtils = new LockscreenUtils();
        btnUnlock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUnlock);
        btnUnlock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // unlock home button and then screen on button press
                if(textView.getText().toString().equals("1234"))
                unlockHomeButton();
            }
        });
    }

    // Handle events of calls and unlock screen if necessary
    private class StateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                unlockHomeButton();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    // Don't finish Activity on Back press
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        return;
    }

    // Handle button clicks
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, android.view.KeyEvent event) {

        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
                || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)
                || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
                || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA)) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {


            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    // handle the key press events here itself
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP
                || (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
                || (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {

            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Lock home button
    public void lockHomeButton() {
        mLockscreenUtils.lock(LockScreenActivity.this);
    }

    // Unlock home button and wait for its callback
    public void unlockHomeButton() {
        mLockscreenUtils.unlock();
    }

    // Simply unlock device when home button is successfully unlocked
    @Override
    public void onLockStatusChanged(boolean isLocked) {
        if (!isLocked) {
            unlockDevice();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unlockHomeButton();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void disableKeyguard() {
        KeyguardManager mKM = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock mKL = mKM.newKeyguardLock("IN");
        mKL.disableKeyguard();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void enableKeyguard() {
        KeyguardManager mKM = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock mKL = mKM.newKeyguardLock("IN");
        mKL.reenableKeyguard();
    }

    //Simply unlock device by finishing the activity
    private void unlockDevice()
    {
        finish();
    }

}
```

and here is my LockscreenIntentReceiver.java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.mehuljoisar.lockscreen.LockScreenActivity;
import com.mehuljoisar.lockscreen.R;

public class LockscreenIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Handle actions and display Lockscreen
    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)
                || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
                || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            start_lockscreen(context);
        }

    }

    // Display lock screen
    private void start_lockscreen(Context context) {

        Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, LockScreenActivity.class);

        mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(mIntent);
    }

}
```

and here is my LockscreenService.java

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.mehuljoisar.lockscreen.R;

public class LockscreenService extends Service {

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    // Register for Lockscreen event intents
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        mReceiver = new LockscreenIntentReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        startForeground();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    // Run service in foreground so it is less likely to be killed by system
    private void startForeground() {
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
         .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
         .setTicker(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
         .setContentText("Running")
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
         .setContentIntent(null)
         .setOngoing(true)
         .build();
         startForeground(9999,notification);        
    }

    // Unregister receiver
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}
```

and here is my LockscreenUtils.java

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.mehuljoisar.lockscreen.R;

public class LockscreenUtils {

    // Member variables
    private OverlayDialog mOverlayDialog;
    private OnLockStatusChangedListener mLockStatusChangedListener;


    // Interface to communicate with owner activity
    public interface OnLockStatusChangedListener
    {
        public void onLockStatusChanged(boolean isLocked);
    }

    // Reset the variables
    public LockscreenUtils() {
        reset();
    }

    // Display overlay dialog with a view to prevent home button click
    public void lock(Activity activity) {

        if (mOverlayDialog == null) {
            mOverlayDialog = new OverlayDialog(activity);
            mOverlayDialog.show();
            mLockStatusChangedListener = (OnLockStatusChangedListener) activity;
        }
    }

    // Reset variables
    public void reset() {
        if (mOverlayDialog != null) {
            mOverlayDialog.dismiss();
            mOverlayDialog = null;
        }
    }

    // Unlock the home button and give callback to unlock the screen
    public void unlock() {
        if (mOverlayDialog != null) {
            mOverlayDialog.dismiss();
            mOverlayDialog = null;
            if(mLockStatusChangedListener!=null)
            {
                mLockStatusChangedListener.onLockStatusChanged(false);
            }
        }
    }

    // Create overlay dialog for lockedscreen to disable hardware buttons
    private static class OverlayDialog extends AlertDialog {
        public OverlayDialog(Activity activity) {
            super(activity, R.style.OverlayDialog);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();

            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);


            params.type = LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
            params.dimAmount = 0.0F;
            params.width = 0;
            params.height = 0;
            params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
            getWindow().setAttributes(params);
            getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                    0xffffff);
            setOwnerActivity(activity);
            setCancelable(false);
        }

        // consume touch events
        public final boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionevent) {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

last but not least .. here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mehuljoisar.lockscreen"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.2" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />


    <application

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mehuljoisar.lockscreen.LockScreenActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".utils.LockscreenService" >
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".utils.LockscreenIntentReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you try `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);` ?

Comment: I have already added it in the LockScreenUtils. java class but when I add it in the onCreate method in LockScreenActivity.java the application crashes and it doesnt open

Comment: now I tried quick solution from eclipse and it added this @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override to let me be able to write getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled (false) and the home button is still enabled –

Answer (score 0):

Use below method for hiding home/menu button:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
```

Or use

```
 getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled (false)
```

to disable interaction with the home/up affordance.

Comment: recieved an error saying the call requires min sdk"14" and when I changed the minSdk to 14 my application didnt start it crashes. @kishuDroid

Comment: What does your logcat say ?

Comment: add android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" to your actvity in manifest.

Comment: look please for what my logcat said . and i added the theme

Comment: all of that happens only when i change the min sdk from 11 to 14

Comment: now I tried quick solution from eclipse and it added this @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override to let me be able to write  getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled (false)
and the home button is still enabled

Comment: See for your error :   There was indeed an occurrence of "onAttachedToWindow" in one of the empty base classes. It will workafter removing that override.